# Related to reactjs import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

Even if I have included type: module in package.json.
Help me!!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import axios from "axios";
const currencyconverter = () => { 


useEffect(() => {
    axios({
        method:"GET",
        url: ""
    })
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
    })
}, []);

return ( 
    <div> 
        <h1>This is a function component view</h1> 
    </div> 
) 
} 

ReactDOM.render( <ExampleComponent />, document.getElementById('app') );
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you used  which is not imported.